# My application doesn't show the data in Internal Memory

Tags: java, android

We're developing an application which is having the problem of not displaying the data in the internal memory.

We actually think that the error is inside the method show and array but can't figure it out where. We would be grateful if you could help us solve this problem.

Here is the logcat.

[image]

and our code

```
public class DBActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView name1 , surname1 , idnumber1;
    @Override
    protected  void  onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_db);
        name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
        surname1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.surname);
        idnumber1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idnumber);
    }


    public void show(View view){


        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput("Rank It Up.txt");

            int read = -1;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((read=fileInputStream.read()) != -1)
            {
                buffer.append((char) read);
            }


            Log.d("Rank It Up",buffer.toString());

            String m = buffer.toString();
            String[] data = m.split(" ");

            String name2       = data[0];
            String surname2    = data[1];
            String idnumber2   = data[2];

            name1.setText(name2);
            surname1.setText(surname2);
            idnumber1.setText(idnumber2);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void back(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Main page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, profile.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Who calls the`show` method?

Comment: The show method is called by the user.

Comment: Also, even if the FileNotFoundException or IOException is caught, you'll still display the "Data Found" toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear.  You're getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception in the `show` method.

It is likely this block of code right here:

```
        String[] data = m.split(" ");

        String name2       = data[0];
        String surname2    = data[1];
        String idnumber2   = data[2];
```

The code is not checking the length of "data" before accessing it.  This this instead:

```
    String[] data = m.split(" ");
    String name2 = (data.length > 0) ? data[0] : "";
    String surname2 = (data.length > 1) ? data[1] : "";
    String idnumber2 = (data.length > 2) ? data[2] : "";
```

As so why you aren't getting the string in the format you expect, that's a separate issue to debug.

Comment: Thank you. we will try your solution to our problem.

Comment: We have tried your solution, it work nicely but all the answer goes to array 0 and combine everything together so could you solve that problem